# Can Spring Cloud Stream work with Spring Cloud Kubernetes?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I haven't seen any example of combining the two, even though it makes sense they'll work together (because of being both subprojects of Spring Cloud). I want to use Spring Cloud Stream (Reactive Processing) for reading from Kafka and writing to MongoDB with the Reactive Mongo driver. Can I use Spring Cloud Config and Spring Cloud Kubernetes for a remote git configuration server, even though the application is an event-driven application and not a requests-based API?

It's pretty unclear how to plug these Kubernetes and config projects into Spring Cloud Stream, and in general, it's unclear to me if all of the other Spring Cloud projects can work with Spring Cloud Stream reactively. For instance, I couldn't also find a reference for using Spring Cloud Sleuth & Zipkin with Spring Cloud Stream. Can someone make it clearer for me and reference code examples if exists?

Comment: how _exactly_ is spring-cloud-kubernetes supposed to help you here and in what context? your question is vague, at best